# How to read relationships in Eclipse UML Designer's class diagram?

Tags: eclipse, uml, emf

I doesn't understand how to read relationships in class diagrams in Eclipse UML Designer. I have a simple diagram with relationship properties displayed.

[image]

I removed navigable from 'legs' and owned from 'bodys' and received above picture which surprised me. Why class Body now have attribute bodys? I expected that Body would rather have legs attribute added. Is this some kind of error in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The arrow points FROM the Leg TO the body. That means that the leg knows who the body is. The body doesn't specifically knows who the leg is, because there is no arrow to it.

I would recomment other UML tools (like Dia) for a stricter usage of the UML conventions.